# Child relationship expressions __r in SOSL

Tags: relationships, sosl, childrelationship

Is that possible to have a child relationship expressions `__r in SOSL`

```
List<List<SObject>> searchList = [FIND :searchText+'*' IN All Fields 
    RETURNING Account (id,name,industry), 
    Contact(id,name,email,firstname,lastname),
    Opportunity(id,name,stagename,closedate),lead(id,name,email,phone)];
```

Comment: @AdrianLarson Somehow, I'm not surprised that it linked back to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The only supported operations are outlined in [RETURNING FieldSpec](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_returning.htm#topic-title).

The following is the format:

```
RETURNING ***ObjectTypeName*** 
    [(FieldList [WHERE conditionExpression] [ORDER BY Clause] [LIMIT n] [OFFSET n])] 
    [, ObjectTypeName [(FieldList [WHERE conditionExpression] [ORDER BY Clause] [LIMIT n] [OFFSET n])]]
```